# Create Variable from part of file

Tags: c#

Hi having trouble working out where to start with creating a variable from a file created by Windows Remote Assistance. I need to extract the port from the text file so i can create an ssh tunnel allowing remote assistance from anywhere.

the port appears after the ip address in 'RCTICKET="65538,1,192.168.9.22:7532,' The colon is the first one in the whole file so I think I need to search for the first ":" and then copy the 4 digits that come after it unless the port is 5 digits ( I think here checking if the 5th character is a comma meaning a 4 digit port of if its a number meaning a 5 digit port )

Any help where to start with this I've been googling for hours just can't think how to put this in a search term.

Below is an example of test.msrcincident the file created by Microsoft Remote Assistance that i need to extract the port from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<UPLOADINFO TYPE="Escalated"><UPLOADDATA USERNAME="jon"          LHTICKET="BDF9C9782B31A1BC276C029A169930ABB4490E2088169FA45A3A095258F5C54D345F4D793363E2C9   B924C5D6A38210AF2E86B3E3D33E5BEB3E35729ECDA88D5F5CE23879899768432726AF419FA2147194F4358BA2A0F245C4307EC8CAB882E2B670977562E5423C90EC336A15BA3DC57496F1EBB26B55B449B45FBD317CD4E422186EA7989F78C6FC3019BCF5831B1E060B174C5254D92448992A543079E576A66617F8B5BEA4C5961FC75C0B67F28B996CD4F1247DBC1C725B9D69B094B53AE24A533501A607CF119ED99C34F0C7210376C6564A48E25871AA32934409D981CF63F60DA956B0877AFBD669DFC321D16D55A34B9949AE0B26B6EEB473915AC416ABFC1129C08021F4011F1F0D1869BB86842C0218C03286C956FC7897B319E0B3A495EBA8ED41835E84E6BAD6B30199F6ACF191B6529DF2C5A264F578AF3B31A84997DA9C4BF1F8AD9E4931F99AE94A0E66D941F050AC0B025523148A95D24E60A6C548341C486BB40089B2088F5FE49AC966D65B728E36E0D7D76C98827335983BEC912DFC0B714DBBBFA060DE62658E7BABDB9BEB45486138950548DA62FDFD6437D0798A67D20CA1911880F58FCDA5F98FA5E0CAEF643171FE9DA8AF046" RCTICKET="65538,1,192.168.9.22:7532,*,U15FphW2EDtpPVdlHmafYLmnO/aVc+YFoFEw30tpjJ+6vJ+LspOTtaqgFoDt3bsp,*,*,P1ooZJPDyfMMTXqlz5hACdwD8F4=" PassStub="TE*0ViGNuB2T6I"     RCTICKETENCRYPTED="1" DtStart="1379526042" DtLength="360" L="0"/></UPLOADINFO>
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: We need context. Show some of the code leading up to this

Comment: use the XML reader to read the document and extract the RCTICKET value.  Then just parse the string to get the data. You are right  to look for the first : then look for the first , after that and create a substring starting at the : index and length of (: index) - (, Index). Give it a try and post back the code if you are having problems.

Comment: Thanks guys, Im trying to get my head round it at the moment will report back when i do. Ive started a new solution working on the xml file Joel the other code is just creating the msra process to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this would get you the data you need, to some extent:

```
    var reader = XDocument.Load("path to XML file");
    var data = reader.Element("UPLOADINFO")
                     .Element("UPLOADDATA")
                     .Attribute("RCTICKET")
    var values = data.Split(',');
```

You will need to work with that RCTICKET string to extract the value you need. It would be a bit safer to work with commas, colons, and whatnot in the context of a single attribute instead of the whole file. Caveat: When I generated an incident file, I ended up with multiple IP addresses in the RCTICKET field. I have multiple VPNs and ethernet adapters in my machine. You will have to pick the right one.

You will also want to handle failures if the XML isn't in the format we expect, or if the file is otherwise inaccessible. You can do this with a try/catch and/or checking for nulls.

Comment: Thanks for this just getting my head round it, forgot about the multiple IP problem - Is it easier to scan for two ports and then forward them both or attempt to detect which IP I want the port of?

Comment: Presumably you would find the values that look like IP addresses (probably safer to use a regular expression than assume it is the third element in the list) and then capture the port associated with the IP address that is part of the subnet you are on. I'm assuming you know which IP addresses you are responsible for.

Comment: Im part of a remote support company that uses 3rd party software to help our users who arnt connected to the domain. The program will call to the internet to get the public IP and then pass that along with the incident file whilst creating a reverse ssh tunnel. For a small amount of coding it seems better than continuing to pay a third party site. Will crack on with what you've shown me and report back thank you very much for the help